# A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'. Widget return value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a declaration

```
bool _glutenFree = false;
```

When I try to use an assignment operator as below

```
_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'];
```

I get an error message

**A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.**

To check the value of "widget.currentFilters['gluten']"

I tried using the print command and found that the value is false.

Now when I change the assignment statement to

```
_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'] == true;
```

The program works.

Could you please enlighten me with the issue

Answer (score 1):

It should be `bool? _glutenFree = false;`

Notice the `?` after the `bool` type. It represents that the variable `_glutenFree` can be `null`.

Currently, the `currentFilters` can return nullable or a value of type `bool` and your variable `currentFilters` is declared as a non-nullable type of bool.

---

For more info on `Dart's Sound null safety` head to https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Now it gives me a same error on : children: [
                _buildSwitchListTile(
                  'Gluten Free',
                  'Only Include Gluten Free Meals',
                  _glutenFree,
                  (newValue) => setState(
                    () {
                      _glutenFree = newValue!;
                    },
                  ),
                ),

Comment: what is ``_buildSwitchListTile`` add more codes please

Answer (score 1):

I tried few of the solutions myself. If I add `!` at the end like:

```
_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten']!
```

code will crash.

But

```
_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'] ?? false;
```

is the best possible answer to your problem.

If you use bool? _glutenfree that is fine as well

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'] ?? false;`.

`??` means that if `widget.currentFilters['gluten']` returns `null`, return `false`, otherwise return whatever value was returned by `widget.currentFilters['gluten']`.

So, in a sense, we provided a default value of `false` to return in case the returned value was `null`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten']!;
```

try this as for null safety you need to add'!'.

Comment: is the value of gluten a boolen variable?

Comment: If `widget.currentFilters['gluten']` is null, this code will crash. It might be better to use a null coalescing operator. If the value is null, then it's probably safe to assume that the 'gluten' filter is not active. If that's the case, then `_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'] ?? false;` might be best.